# android retrofit consuming asp.net web api [FromBody] always null

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, json, retrofit

I am consuming a web api wrote in c#, MVC, that looks like:

```
public IEnumerable<Day> Post([FromBody] string postObject)
```

Using fiddler or poster I can post to that REST service since my body has a = before my sending JSON, something like

```
={"BillTypeId":"4","RestId":"1"}
```

Using retrofit to make this call I can not send that initial = and my request looks like

```
{"BillTypeId":"4","RestId":"1"}
```

That makes the rest service receive always a null parameter.
Do you know a way to send it before my json? Since I am calling that rest like this

```
void postToGetDayList(@Body ResquestListenerBillType request, Callback<List<Day>> callback);
```

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't fixed your issue, I think you can refer to my following code:

WebAPI:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }        

    // POST api/values
    public string Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
        return value;
    }        
}
```

Retrofit WebAPIService:

```
public interface WebAPIService {
    @GET("/api/values")
    List<String> listValues();

    @POST("/api/values")
    String postValues(@Body String value);
}
```

Call `webAPIService.postValues("BNK");`

You will find the result as the following image. Hope this helps!
[image: Debug info]

Comment: Can `@Body` be used with one than one param ? `String postValues(@Body String value1, String value2);`

Comment: @SimpleGuy sorry bro, I haven't tried Android for years, however IMO you can use a POJO class. pls refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56263599/retrofit-post-request-with-body-parameters-android/56263882 to see if it can help you or not

Answer (score 0):

before send class convert to string and add one " fist string and add one " on last string then send body
my client API is :

```
   [Put("/WebPage/{key}/")]
        Task<string> PutWebPage([AliasAs("key")]string id, [Body]string value);
```

sample code is :

```
   WebPageModel webPageModelSave = new WebPageModel();
                webPageModelSave = ObjectCopier.CloneClass(Public.CashEntity.webPageModel);
                webPageModelSave.Address = uxLabel_AddressTitle.Text;

                string codeingData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(webPageModelSave);
               codeingData = ArmanSerialize.CryptoString.Encrypt(codeingData, "5552552");
                string resutlt = await Public.Helper.ApiServer.PutWebPage("123", "\""+codeingData+"\"");
```

and on server remove the " fist and last string like this:

```
// PUT api/<controller>/5
        [HttpPut("{id}/")]
        public string Put(string id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
            string removeCotation = value.Remove(value.Length - 1, 1).Remove(0, 1);

            string valueItem = ArmanSerialize.CryptoString.Decrypt(value, "5552552");
            string baseUrl = Request.Host.Host;
            baseUrl = baseUrl.ToLower().Replace("http://", "").Replace("https://", "");
            var serverID = 123;
            if (id.Replace("\"", "") == serverID.Replace("\"","") && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(valueItem))
            {
                WebPageModel webPageModel = new WebPageModel();
                webPageModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WebPageModel>(valueItem);
                EntityFrameworkCore.LogicLayer logicLayer = new EntityFrameworkCore.LogicLayer();
                logicLayer.UpdateWebPageModel(webPageModel);
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject("OK");
            }
            else
            {
                //error
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject("Error");
            }
        }
```

I test it on xamarin form and asp.net core 3 its work it.