# Retrofit POST Request with body parameters android

Tags: java, android, http-post, retrofit, retrofit2

I need to execute post request with retrofit but i have a problem which i can't understand very well. Before trying with code i tested api call with **Postman** and request look like this:

[image: capture1]
[image]

Here is my android code:

```
public class API {

private static <T> T builder(Class<T> endpoint) {

    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Utils.API_BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(endpoint);
}
public static AllRequests request() {
    return builder(AllRequests.class);
}
}
```

**EDIT** request:

```
@POST("api/android-feedback")
@Headers({"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Authorization: F#@3FA@#Rad!@%!2s"})
Call<String> sendFeedback(@Body FeedbackBody body);
```

FeedbackBody:

```
public class FeedbackBody{
private final String email;
private final String feedback;

public FeedbackBody(String email, String feedback){
    this.email = email;
    this.feedback = feedback;
}
```

}

And finally i construct the request and wait for response, the problem is that i receive message in onFail method

```
   private void sendFeedbackRequest(){
    API.request().sendFeedback(new FeedbackBody("testmeil@meil.com", "test feedback").enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
            goToMainActivity();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(SplashScreenActivity.this, R.string.try_again_later, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

**EDIT:**
Still not working.. i think i figure it out where can be the problem, because server side wait for simple POST request without Json formatting, i think Retrofit use JSON formatting by default, and if i send POST request and format Body parameters with JSON the server will fail to parse my request, is there any chance to send simple POST request like at POSTMAN without formatting with JSON ?

- Php api wait request to be send like this:

> $_POST['feedback'] = 'blabla';
>       $_POST['email'] = 'blabla..';

and if he receive Json format request can't parse it and because of that i receive fail response.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to create request( POJO Class)

```
public class FeedbackRequest {
   public String email;
   public String feedback;
}
```

when you call `sendFeedbackRequest()` pass the `FeedbackRequest` like below"

```
FeedbackRequest req = new FeedbackRequest();
req.email= "email";
req.feedback= "feedback"
sendFeedbackRequest(req)
```

after that your `sendFeedbackRequest()` should be like this

```
  private void sendFeedbackRequest(FeedbackRequest request){
      API.request().sendFeedback(request).enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
        goToMainActivity();
      }

      @Override
      public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(SplashScreenActivity.this, R.string.try_again_later, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

And your retrofit request should be like this,

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("api/android-feedback")
@Headers({"Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: F31daaw313415"})
Call<String> sendFeedback(@Body FeedbackRequest request);
```

Now it should work. feel free to ask anything.

Comment: I tried your answer but still not work properly, you can check my edit question, i will be glad if you can help me with.

Comment: change your `sendFeedbackRequest(final String feedback, final String email)` to `sendFeedbackRequest(FeedbackBody body)`

Comment: i change it, but again i send JSON format and server can't parse it, is it any possibility to send them raw POST without formatting it as JSON.

Comment: can you update your current code(edited) related to this issue to a google doc and paste the link here

Comment: you are doing it wrong. check `sendFeedbackRequest()` function in your code and my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193813/discussion-between-sajith-and-kristiyan-varbanov).

Answer (score 1):

You are using a Gson converter factory. It might be easier to create a single object that represents your body, and use that instead of all individual parameters. That way, you should be able to simple follow along with the examples on the Retrofit website.[enter link description here](https://square.github.io/retrofit/#requestBody)
There are also many site that let you generate your Plain Old Java Objects for you, like [this one](http://www.objgen.com/pojo):

E.g. your Api call:

```
@POST("api/android-feedback")
Call<String> sendFeedback(@Body FeedbackBody feedback);
```

And your FeedbackBody class:

```
public class FeedbackBody{
    private final String email;
    private final String feedback;

    public FeedbackBody(String email, String feedback){
        this.email = email;
        this.feedback = feedback;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your answer but still not work properly, you can check my edit question, i will be glad if you can help me with.

Answer (score 0):

Java:

```
@POST("/api/android-feedback")
Call<String> sendFeedback(@Body FeedbackBody feedback);
```

Kotlin:

```
@POST("/api/android-feedback")
fun sendFeedback(@Body feedback: FeedbackBody): Call<String>
```

Also, probably you forgot leading slash in the endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

```
  val formBody: RequestBody = FormBody.Builder()
            .add("username", LoginRequest.username)
            .add("password", LoginRequest.password)
            .add("grant_type",LoginRequest.grant_type)
            .add("client_id", LoginRequest.client_id)
            .add("client_secret", LoginRequest.client_secret)
            .add("cleartext", LoginRequest.cleartext)
            .build()

@POST(EndPoints.GENERATE_TOKEN_URL)
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    suspend fun getLogin(
        @Body formBody: RequestBody
    ): LoginResponse
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).