# How can I pass the param and value to post api using retrofit in android?

Tags: android, retrofit2

[image]

> ```
> @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
> @POST("answer")
> fun sendAnswer(@Header("token") token :String, @Body answer: SendAnswerModel):Call<SendAnswerResultModel>
> ```

here is my model class

```
data class Vote2019Answer(
    @SerializedName("question_id") @Expose val id: Int,
    @SerializedName("answer") @Expose val answer: String)
```

another model class

```
data class SendAnswerModel(
    @SerializedName("answer") @Expose val answer: List<Vote2019Answer> )
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrofit and GET using parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24100372/retrofit-and-get-using-parameters)

Comment: please be specific about your question. First search on SO after post such question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56263882/7335321

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `json object / json array` using [@Body](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/Body.html) by converting the `json model` to `POJO` ( using `GSON`) .

Check [this](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/Body.html) out !

Answer (score 1):

Try the following way.

Your API endpoint

```
@POST("url")
Call<ResponseBody> yourAPi(@Body JSONArray jsonArray);
```

And API call using param data

```
String[] answer = {"aaa","bbb","ccc"}
JSONArray jsArray= new JSONArray();
try {
    for(int i = 0; i < answer.length; i++) {
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        object.put("question_id",i+1);
        object.put("answer",answer[i]);
        jsArray.put(object);
    }

} catch (JSONException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}   
// here you can call your api 
Call<ResponseBody> call =  yourApiService.yourAPi(jsArray);
// ........
```